# index of bash string item with ifs separator

Tags: bash

Let's say I have this string:

```sh
NAMES="Mike&George&Norma"
IFS=$'&'
for NAME in $NAMES
do
  echo ${NAME}
done
```

So I can loop through the NAMES.

But what if I only need George, i.e. the name at index 1?

How can I get NAMES[1]?

Comment: Btw.: `$` is in not necessary in `IFS=$'&'`.

Answer (score 2):

If `mapfile` aka `readarray` is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

names="Mike&George&Norma"

mapfile -td '&' name <<< "$names"

printf '%s\n' "${name[@]}"
```

Prints all elements/strings in between the `&`, so

```
printf '%s\n' "${name[0]}"
printf '%s\n' "${name[1]}"
printf '%s\n' "${name[2]}"
```

Should print them names one by one.

See the *builtin* section of the bash manual https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$ NAMES="Mike&George&Norma"; 
$ echo "$NAMES" | cut -d'&' -f2

 George
```

field counting starts with 1, unlike array indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Using OP's current code one idea would be to add a counter to the loop processing, eg:

```
NAMES="Mike&George&Norma"

loop_ctr=-1
match_ctr=1

origIFS="${IFS}"                 # save current IFS
IFS=$'&'

for NAME in $NAMES
do
    ((loop_ctr++))
    [[ "${loop_ctr}" -ne "${match_ctr}" ]] &&    # if loop_ctr != match_ctr then skip to next pass through loop
    continue

    echo ${NAME}
done

IFS="${origIFS}"                 # reset to original IFS
```

This generates as output:

```
George
```

**NOTE**: My preference would be to parse the string into an array (via `mapfile/readarray`) ... and @jetchisel beat me to that idea :-)

Comment: I would have deleted my `mapfile` answer if you did not deleted  yours.

Comment: I was in the process of additional editing that basically repeated what you had just posted so ... twas easier to just delete that (incomplete) chunk of my answer; no biggie ... it's not like we can cash in our SO points for anything useful :-)